# How we Integrated Libgit2 library in Visual Studion 2010 Windows Application

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

I downloaded two DLLs (**libgit2sharp.dll** and **git2.dll**) from [this site](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/DLL/l/LibGit2Sharp/Download_LibGit2Sharp_DLL_Files.htm).

After that I successfully added **Libgit2sharp.dll** by add reference in my .NET Windows application. Now when I add **git2.dll** by add reference in my .NET Windows Application, it gives an error:

```
a reference to 'C:\User\nitesh\git2.dll' could not be added please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component
```

Can anyone please help me understand the problem?

Answer (score 5):

> I downloaded two DLLs (**libgit2sharp.dll** and **git2.dll**) from [this site](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/DLL/l/LibGit2Sharp/Download_LibGit2Sharp_DLL_Files.htm).

First off, this is not a distribution channel that the libgit2/libgit2sharp team has anything to do with.

**Install as a NuGet package:**

Official releases are **[available](http://www.nuget.org/packages/LibGit2Sharp)** as a NuGet package if you prefer to download pre-built sources. See this **[post](https://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget)** which explains how to install the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.

This is the easiest way to make LibGit2Sharp available to your project.

**Build from the source code:**

You can download the source code and build the C# code into `LibGit2Sharp.dll` from https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp, which includes the pre-built version of `git2.dll` which works for the particular version of the C# code.

Easiest way to build the assembly is by launching the `build.libgit2sharp.cmd`. This will create a `Build` folder into which you'll find the LibGit2Sharp.dll and a `NativeBinaries` folder with the native binaries.

> Now when I add **git2.dll** by add reference in my .NET Windows Application, it gives an error

As for the error message, it sounds like you're trying to add the `git2.dll` to the project as though it were a CLR/.NET assembly. It is however built from C and isn't something VS is going to do anything useful with. You do not need to add it to your project.

It does need to be available for libgit2sharp to load. The following graph depicts the folder hierarchy that libgit2sharp expects

```
NativeBinaries+
              |___amd64+
                       |___git2-{shortsha}.dll
                       |___git2-{shortsha}.pdb
              |_____x86+
                       |___git2-{shortsha}.dll
                       |___git2-{shortsha}.pdb
```

**Note:** This folder structure will be dynamically created in your project output folder if you installed LibGit2Sharp as a NuGet package. However, if you built the project from the source code, you'll have to copy this folder structure as part of your project build process yourself.

Comment: As per Your Instruction We download source code from this site https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp after that Build it,and execute build.libgit2sharp.cmd after execute cmd we add libgit2sharp.dll  in our application from this path like where code reside"\\libgit2sharp-vNext\LibGit2Sharp\bin\Debug". Now we can create repositry in application by code then its throw error. error Is:- The type initializer for 'LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods' threw an exception. we code writing such using (Repository repo = new epository(@"D:\LibGit2Sharp1")){ foreach (Commit commit in repo.Commits){ }

Comment: That error comes from not being able to find the libgit2 dll or having the wrong version. Make sure that the name of the file has the appropriate suffix indicating the version that corresponds to the libgit2sharp version.

Comment: @NiteshOO7 See the note in the answer: the `NativeBinaries` folder hierarchy has to live next to the LibGit2sharp.dll once the project is built.

Comment: Can you tell me guys we Add both dll (LibGit2sharp.dll & git2.dll)in our application.ya either only one dll (LibGit2sharp.dll) in our application.And Guys I requested to u ,if you possible you will send working dll in this mail id "nitesh.kumar@lakshyadigital.com"